# running a php script via cron, how can I log any output?

Tags: php, logging, cron

Morning all,

I have a php script which I have been testing, and seems to run fine when I call it from the command line.

I now want to automate it via cron, how can I get the outputs I have put into the file as checkpoints into a log file?

eg I have some simple echo commands in the script and I'd like the output to appear inside an existing log file (so that it get's automatically rotated etc)

thanks,

Greg

Comment: UNIX-based crons will email the output(s) of the job to the user under whose ID the job is running. So if you don't want to mess with output redirection as suggested in the other answers, you could just look at those auto-emails.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cron command to run:

```
/path/to/php -f /path/to/script.php >> /path/to/logfile.txt
```

Comment: `>>` to append to the log file.

Comment: thanks -  if I use /var/log/cron as the logfile, is that ok? That way it will get automatically archived, trimmed etc

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
function logToFile($filename, $msg)
{ 
    $fd = fopen($filename, "a");
    $str = "[" . date("Y/m/d h:i:s", mktime()) . "] " . $msg;
    fwrite($fd, $str . "\n");
    fclose($fd);
}

function logToMail($msg, $address)
{ 
    $str = "[" . date("Y/m/d h:i:s", mktime()) . "] " . $msg;   
    mail($address, "Log message", $str);
}

function logToDB($msg, $type)
{ 
    // open connection to database
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "joe", "pass") or die ("Unable to connect!");
    mysql_select_db("logdb") or die ("Unable to select database!");

    // formulate and execute query
    $query = "INSERT INTO log (date, type, msg) VALUES(NOW(), '$type', '$msg')";
    mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. " .mysql_error());

    // close connection
    mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem here is that if the php script fails for any reason, the logging method may never get executed. The accepted answer above will send any script output to the log file.